# Sending keys to input field with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, shopify, sendkeys

I am trying to click on the input fields for the payment information, then submit keys to those input fields. I discovered that they are in iframes but I have had no luck switching to the different frames. I attached a picture of the html as well as what the page looks like. Any help would be appreciated! Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print('Browser Successfully Iitialized!')

driver.get('https://kith.com/products/new-balance-696-beige-pink')
input()
print('Beginning Checkout Process!')
print('Posting Customer Information...')
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id('g-recaptcha-response')
        print('Captcha Detected!')
        print('Solve Captcha...')
        captcha = True
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('No Captcha Detected!')
        captcha = False
        break

email_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_email"]').send_keys('johndoe44@gmail.com')
fname_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_first_name"]').send_keys('John')
lname_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_last_name"]').send_keys('Doe')
address_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_address1"]').send_keys('12345 Street')
city_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_city"]').send_keys('City')
state_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_province"]/option[22]').click()
zipcode_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_zip"]').send_keys('46001')
phone_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkout_shipping_address_phone"]').send_keys('1234567891')

if captcha == True:
    while captcha is True:
        time.sleep(3)
        try:
            cont_shipping = driver.find_element_by_name('button').click()
            button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn__content')
            if button.text == 'Continue to payment method':
                print('Captcha Solved!')
                captcha = False
        except:
            captcha = True

driver.find_element_by_name('button').click()
print('Posting Shipping Information...')        
shipping_url = driver.current_url
shipping_url.replace("previous_step=contact_information&step=shipping_method", "")
payment_url = shipping_url + 'previous_step=shipping_method&step=payment_method'
driver.get(payment_url)
print('Posting Payment Information...')
try:
    el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="payment-gateway-subfields-1427382"]/div[3]/div[2]')
    el.click()
    el.send_keys('John Doe')
except ElementNotVisibleException:
    print('Error')
```

[Image of the html and screen of the input field/fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXKXB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code after click PayPal button :

```
frame_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.name, "injectedUl"))
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.find_element_by_name("injectedUl"));
driver.find_element_by_id("email"))send_keys("abc@gmail.com");
driver.find_element_by_id("password")send_keys("asdsa");
driver.find_element_by_id("btnLogin")).click();
```

Payment Gateway options (Email, Password..) Present under iframe so first switch into iframe and then  perform actions

Comment: Thank you for this reply! Do you think you could assist on how I can send keys to the Credit Card information (Credit Card #, Name on Card, Expiration, and Security Code)?